# Alert innerHTML of element with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to traverse a document and get the contents of an element thought I'm being returned `undefined`...

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll(".home .something .test");
var c = el.textContent;
alert(c);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fevfymz1/

Can anybody see whats going wrong?

Comment: `el` is a collection of elements(NodeList)

Comment: `var el = document.querySelector(".home .something .test");`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fevfymz1/1/

Comment: querySelectorAll potentially returns more than one, right?  So this means logically you'd need an array to hold it (technically not an array, but conceptually an array).  If you think you'd have one, you should be using querySelector or you should take the first element of "el".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var c = el[0].textContent;
```

Because `document.querySelectorAll()` returns an array of matches

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll(".home .something .test");
var c = el[0].textContent;
alert(c);
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <div class="something">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>asdasd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <span class="test">Alert this</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdasd</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite correct. It returns a collection (`NodeList`) which is [not an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Why_is_NodeList_not_an_Array).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `loop` because `document.querySelectorAll()` returns an `array`.

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll(".home .something .test");
for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
   alert(el[i].textContent);
}
//var c = el.textContent;

//alert(c);
```

```html
<div class="home">
   <div class="something">
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>asdasd</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <span class="test">Alert this</span>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>asdasd</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```